# Sorting music in iOS by album only

Tags: ios, music, apple-music

When you try to sort by album on iOS, the player sorts by album and then it also sorts by artist.

How can you get it to sort by album **only**?

Edit: I should clarify that I’m using an iphone 4 with the latest updates, so this question is about whatever version of iOS runs on iPhone 4

Answer (score 1):

Go to your album view, then use View -> Sort By -> Title.

Comment: The menu you describe does not exist

Comment: Open iTunes, select Album from the left sidebar, then go to the top of your screen. There should be a bold apple icon, a bold iTunes, File, Edit, Song, View, Controls, Account, Window, Help. Select the View, and the submenu Sort By.